# Can't create graph from node/edge collections in ArangoDB 2.2.0

Tags: arangodb, aql

Last week was released ArangoDB 2.2.0 with many nice changes. I want to refactor some AQL graph queries since the API has changed from 2.x to 2.2.x and many methods are now deprecated. The issue is that I can't create a graph from my node/edge collections from the UI, I'm getting the following error:

```
Sorry your graph seems to be empty
```

Having a look at the logs there is no error.

Any clues?

[image: Error screenshot]

EDIT:

I include the UI behaviour I commented:

By default, from/to collections do not show up:

[image: From/To collections do not show up]

When clicking the add button or near to it, from/to collections fields show up. It's not clear to me I should do it to be able to set up the edge definition.

[image: When clicking the add button or near to it, from/to collections fields show up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out the issue, a UI related one. When specifying the edge definitions, only "Edge defintions" field is displayed but not "fromCollections" and "toCollections" fields. I was a bit confused about it as well, since in the [docs](http://docs.arangodb.org/General-Graphs/Management.html) I noticed these concepts (in 2.1.2 only edges collection name was necessary). By clicking in the add button (or around it), these fields show up and everything works as expected when filling them in.

Answer (score 0):

The graph viewer expects a graph to contain at least one vertex.
This message indicates, that your graph does not contain any data. Please make sure that your vertex collections contain at least one document.

Comment: Collections aren't empty, that's not the issue here.

Comment: please take a look at the system collection _graphs and look for your graph there. It should have been converted to the new edge definitions concept. If this is the case and the collection defined there under _from contain at least one vertex everything should work

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused by your description.
In all versions below 2.2 we offered a dialog to configure your graph viewer before actually showing it (there you could select a vertex and an edge collection). Are you using a bookmarked version of this page?
It will not work any more.
If this is the case, please use the normal graphs tab from the menu and create a new graph where you reference the collections you already have.

If this is not the case the answer above is correct.

Comment: Hi @mchacki, thanks for your reply. Yes, I first created the graph by specifying the edge and node collections, but after it and when trying to explore the graph, the above error appears. As I commented in the other response, collections aren't empty. I'm importing data introduced in an ArangoDB 2.1.2 instance, did the way of storing/managing graphs change? In version 2.1.2 I just had to specify the edge and nodes collections as you say, but in version 2.2.0 the graph creation dialog has changed, appearing the edge definitions concept, which wasn't necessary before.

Comment: I just found out the issue, a UI related one. When specifying the edge definitions, only "Edge defintions" field is displayed but not "fromCollections" and "toCollections" fields. I was a bit confused about it as well, since in the docs I noticed these concepts (in 2.1.2 only edges collection name was necessary). By clicking in the add button, these fields show up and everything works as expected when filling them in (this should be the default behaviour).

Comment: you are right. will be added for next bugfix release. Thanks for pointing this out.